# Is it possible to work with older iPhone/iPAD simulator (3.2, 4.0, 4.2) with Xcode 4.4 + Mountain Lion

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.4

I recently upgraded from Xcode 3.2.3 to Xcode 4.4 + Mountain Lion (in order to test my app on 5.1 iOS). But it only seems show support for 5.1 iOS simulators and not the older ones.

So, is it possible to work with older iPhone/iPAD simulator (3.2, 4.0, 4.2) with Xcode 4.4 + Mountain Lion.

Could anybody please guide me, how to test my app on older simulators?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can download and install the iOS 5.0 simulator additionally by selecting

Xcode->Preferences;
[image]

And then navigate towards "Downloads" and tap on "Install" on the iOS 5.0 Simulator.

[image]

---

**THIS IS OUTDATED BUT GIVEN FOR REFERENCE**

With older Xcode (iPhone simulator) versions, it used to be possible to simply link the older (unsupported) iPhoneSimulator SDK-Versions into the correct paths but under Mountain Lion that seems to have stopped working. Just for giving some reference on how that was done;

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs $ ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk iPhoneSimulatorh4.3.sdk
root@lobomacpro-4 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs $ ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  306 Aug  6 14:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 Jul 26 23:26 ..
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   83 Aug  6 14:58 iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   83 Aug  6 14:58 iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk
drwxrwxr-x  8 root  admin  272 Oct 28  2011 iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Jul 26 23:26 iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   83 Aug  6 14:58 iPhoneSimulatorh4.1.sdk -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   83 Aug  6 14:59 iPhoneSimulatorh4.2.sdk -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   83 Aug  6 14:59 iPhoneSimulatorh4.3.sdk -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
root@lobomacpro-4 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs $
```

That will actually seem to work as it results into the following options within the simulator;
[image]

Trouble is, on my machine the simulator stops working after startup if any of those unsupported versions are selected. Maybe there still is a way... just I did not get this to work as it used to on older OSs.

Comment: Yes, I also tried the same. But application doesn't start on these older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Only iOS Simulator 5.0 and above is supported by Xcode 4.4 + Mountain Lion.
You can however install iOS 3.0 and iOS 4.0 device debugging support, so that you can still test your apps on devices running iOS 3.0 or 4.0 by going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know about the device debugging support. 
But purchasing all devices is always difficult, thats why looking for the simulator option. 

Yes, I did try copying the old simulator sdks to new sdks folder, the option for running on those simulator did come up in Xcode but application doesn't start in simulator. 
Older Xcode version is unable to compile to compile anymore.

Moreover new Xcode as well as simulator hangs very frequently (too bad). 

It seems like device debugging only option. 

But Apple should have added old simulator support.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download older simulators anymore - sorry.
But you can  download the debugging support for older devices in the preferences.

Xcode - Preferences -> Go to Downloads and then to Components. There you can select several older devices.